# Which skills are lost first if Intelligence drops? Can I choose?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills

As per [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/28744/do-you-get-skill-points-retroactively-for-increased-int), permanent increases to Intelligence retroactively grant new skill points in Pathfinder.

If I lose my Intelligence bonus, is there a rule for which skill I lose first? Can I technically retrain my skills by wearing an Intelligence bonus item for a few days, adding a new skill, then discard a different skill when I remove the item?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

And lo the book says

> Permanent Bonuses: Ability bonuses with a duration greater than 1 day actually increase the relevant ability score after 24 hours. Modify all skills and statistics related to that ability. This might cause you to gain skill points, hit points, and other bonuses. ***These bonuses should be noted separately in case they are removed.***

And thus the question is answered. Except for losing a permanent bonus, true reduction in a stat is super unusual - damage/drain don't really lose the points.