# Grands a Gift or Magic Item Ability Bonus skill points retrospectively

Tags: pathfinder-1e, ability-scores

I just met Noctucular and she grants me an ability bonus +6 as a gift. According to [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/28744/do-you-get-skill-points-retroactively-for-increased-int) all bonuses with a duration of more than 1 day will give a more skill points and all the other stuff. But what is going to happen when I piss off Nocticular and she withdraws the gift? (Same goes for artifacts or magic items, what is going to happen when my Headband of Vast Intelligence is destroyed or stolen). Should I therefore notice what skill points I put where for what reason so I can substract it later, if needed?

Comment: The Headband is also an exception in that it does NOT grant retroactive skill points; see the FAQ entry on its page: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/headband-of-vast-intelligence/

Comment: Though you will have a lot more to worry about than your skill points if Nocticula removes her gift, as you'll take 4d6 points of Charisma drain and 1d10+10 permanent negative levels. And it'll serve you right.